# htaccess rewrite to specific url does not work

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I try to rewrite all languages to /en/ on a site. But I do something wrong and do not know what.
All domain request like https://www.shop.com/de/ or https://www.shop.com/ must rewrite to https://www.shop.com/en/

Why I need this? First my shop must be ready in /en/ language. When everything works fine I will add /de/ and then /nl/.

Does someone have a solution for me? Would be very nice.

Here the code I use in htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine     On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule https://www.shop.com/de/ https://www.shop.com/en/
RewriteRule https://www.shop.com/nl/ https://www.shop.com/en/
RewriteRule https://www.shop.com https://www.shop.com/en/
RewriteRule https://www.shop.com/ https://www.shop.com/en/
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot match full URLs in `RewriteRule`.

You can use these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(de|nl)?/?$ /en/ [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Your solution works great! Only do not understand both index rows. Hope you can explain them. Thanks.

Comment: I just added one new rule `RewriteRule ^(de|nl)?/?$ /en/ [L,NC,R=301]` which matches `/de` or `/nl` or landing page and redirects to `/en/`